# Encrypting Datasource password for JBOSS and Tomcat6

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, jboss, datasource

Is there any way to encrypt datasource password provided to Tomcat6's context.xml and JBoss's mssql-ds.xml?

I can externalize datasource information in a property file and encrypt the password there using Jasypt. But then how Tomcat and JBoss will access this property file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a FAQ in the Tomcat Wiki.

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Password

There is no reliable way to truly protect yourself if you want your service to be able to start up unattended. All techniques that allow unattended startups are merely security-by-obscurity.